# Format One Cell with ColorScale Based on Range of Cell Values

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I need to format a single cell with a gradient color based on the values of a range of cells. Similar to the conditional formatting with a ColorScale, except only applying the formatting to a single cell based on the values of a range of cells.

Most likely this will need to be done in VBA. I can't seem to find a simple way to do this without rewriting a similar script to the built-in ColorScale methods.

Example:

B10 formatted with a color in a scale based upon the values of B10:B40. ColorScale would be type 3 with Low, Mid (50%), and High. But I don't want to format any cells other than B10, just use the values of the range B10:B40

I will then do the same for B11:B41, but only formatting B11, then B12:B42, B13:B43, etc..

All I need is to figure out how to create a ColorScale based on a range of values but only apply the formatting to one of the cells.

Edit:

If someone knows a way to create a color scale script similar to the conditional formatting one built into Excel, that would also be a good fix. If I can just calculate the scale from the values in the range of cells and apply to the one cell with the color grade, that would be a solution.

Comment: No, just separate steps. I don't want to format B11:B40 with the calculation for B10:B40. I just want to calculate the color grade for B10 out of B10:B40 and just apply it to B10. Then I will calculate the color grade for B11 out of B11:B41 and apply it to B11, and so on and so forth. Not incompatible, I guess you just don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are after is a 3-color scale for B10 to B40 (so that B10 acquires a colour based on that cell's ranking in the range) together with a separate rule that applies white formatting (in appearance, no formatting) to B11:B40. The latter rule should be at the top of the list of rules and Stop if True checked.

Comment: That works, but makes things very complicated. I still want to format B11:B41 for example, so you end up with 3-4x the conditional formatting rules and it's not easy to apply.

I'm looking for something that creates a color scale similar to the Excel 3-ColorScale, but allows relative referencing and to only apply formatting to the selected cell. So calculate the color grade from the 30 cells, but only apply the color to the one cell. Essentially trying to create a color scale based on the last 30 days from that cell.

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you! I'll use this solution if a simpler one isn't found.